# Android studio sync gradle Error:Cannot invoke method add() on null object

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

i can't sync android project i add gradle code below. When i sync it's failed and add message: Error:Cannot invoke method add() on null object
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'. I tryed everything, but can't fix it

```
    android {

        def ci_pf = new File('ci.properties')
        if (ci_pf.canRead()) {
            def Properties ci_p = new Properties()
            ci_p.load(new FileInputStream(ci_pf))
            def bld = ci_p['ci_versionCode'].toInteger()
            def bvn = ci_p['ci_versionName']
            def csv = ci_p['ci_compileSdkVersion'].toInteger()
            def btv = ci_p['ci_buildToolsVersion']
            def msv = ci_p['ci_minSdkVersion'].toInteger()
            def tsv = ci_p['ci_targetSdkVersion'].toInteger()
            def cxf = ci_p['ci_cppFlags']
            compileSdkVersion csv
            buildToolsVersion btv
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.nordcurrent.AdSystemTest"
                minSdkVersion msv
                targetSdkVersion tsv
                versionCode bld
                versionName bvn
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                externalNativeBuild {
                    cmake {
                        cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -Wno-nonportable-include-path -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG " + cxf
                        cFlags "-D\"lua_getlocaledecpoint()='.'\" -DLUA_ANSI -DUSE_ANDROID"
                        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
                    }
                }
                ndk {
                    // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
                    // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
                    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
                    jobs 32
                }
            }
            compileSdkVersion = csv
            buildToolsVersion = btv

        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                debuggable true
            }
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
            }
        }
    }



    android.productFlavors {
        create("fat") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
    }



    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDirs 'src/main/jni'
                }
            }
        }
    }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'Millennial', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'

    /** Tune dependency */
    compile  'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```